# Error while running MIFOS

Tags: java

When trying to run `mvn compile` the following errors are encountered

[INFO] Mifos - Reporting ................................. SUCCESS [28.443s]

[INFO] Mifos - Application ............................... FAILURE [44.243s]

[INFO] Mifos - WAR ....................................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Mifos - Acceptance Tests .......................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Mifos - Base Server (Jetty) ....................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Mifos - Workspace Server .......................... SKIPPED

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

### [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:native2ascii-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha- 1:native2ascii (native2ascii) on project mifos-webapp:

### Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.mifos:mifos-webapp:jar:1.12-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.mifos:mifos-db:jar:1.12

in http://maven.mifos.org/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-repository.mifos.org has elapsed or updates are forced at     org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:189)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the old codebase of mifos please refer to the [new mifos wiki](https://github.com/openMF/mifosx/wiki) to get started

You can find the new repository [here](https://github.com/openMF/mifosx)